# How to scroll table to particular tr programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to scroll the html table to particular tr by using Javascript or jquery. Currently I can get the offset of the selected tr .And I am using the scrollTop method .I have tried the following but it is not working for me :

```
var table  = document.getElementById("table");
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[3];
var scrollTo = tr.offsetTop;
table.scrollTop = scrollTo;
```

also I tried with jquery :

```
$('#table').animate({scrollTop:0},50);
```

can anybody help me where am I getting wrong ?

Comment: please provide jsFiddle

Comment: I have added all the code related to the functionality .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/SZKJh/

```
var w = $(window);
var row = $('#tableid').find('tr').eq( line );

if (row.length){
    w.scrollTop( row.offset().top - (w.height()/2) );
}
```

reference :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853216/1982680

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me, try this

```
var elm = document.getElementById(id);
elm.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Super simple and works well.  Seems almost too good to be true - are there any known drawbacks / lack of support for this method?

Comment: Please go through below link to know more information   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Best answer, simple and concise

Comment: Tried other solutions using jQuery, but this simple one line works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here the simple step for scroll top function

```
 var s = $("table tbody > tr:nth-child(20)").position();
 $( "div" ).scrollTop( s.top );
```

Here the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z7Z9/)**