# Table doesn't scroll when using keyboard navigation

Tags: angularjs, scrollview, keyboard-navigation

I have create a scroll-able Angular table and have implemented the content navigation when pressing the up and down keys in order to let the users navigate easily through the results even though the rows get selected the inner content area with the results isn't scrolling.

How can I scroll the inner container as I go up or down, I have created sample plunker to demonstrate the error.

Sample [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/qtkRyVf9EgC00xpnshu7/)

Comment: I have updated the plunker with the solution that i came across. This is not the idea solution but this will give some headsup https://embed.plnkr.co/qtkRyVf9EgC00xpnshu7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay with angular, I would suggest using anchors and scrolling them into the view. You can find a similar problem with a solution using anchors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890060/using-location-and-anchorscroll-to-scroll-a-table-row-into-view).

---

If you have the option to use jQuery, you can simply select the row you want to scroll to (for example by using its class name) and then call the `scrollTop()` function on your table to scroll it to the position of the row. Here is [an example using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/SZKJh/). For reference you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855341/how-to-scroll-table-to-particular-tr-programmatically) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852986/javascript-scroll-to-nth-row-in-a-table/7853216#7853216) stackoverflow question.